# Centrally managed Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins multibranch pipeline.
I have created a Jenkins file with the help of the Pipeline syntax generator.
My Jenkinsfile is working perfectly and as expected.

But now I want to manage this Jenkinsfile centrally so I don't have to copy it to all my (git) repos.
I see there are options to have a generic groovy script and load the methods as a module. 
But this would mean I have to re-write my Jenkinsfile with a different syntax?

I've tried several options but none have succeeded yet.
For example, I have added the jenkinsfile to its own git repo and I have added that repo as a submodule to the (code) repo.
Then I tried in Jenkins to configure like in the image below

Is this the way forward, is there any (easy) way to achieve what I'm trying to get done?

[Jenkins configuration example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRNZM.png)

Answer (score 1):

The Jenkins shared library plugin could help you. Check out the [docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#global-shared-libraries)

Comment: I have looked at this option already. But writing a shared library cannot be done in Jenkins pipeline syntax? Which means I would have to learn and re-write what I have created so far. Also my team needs to learn to do this. I want to have an option where I can use the pipeline syntax and I don't think I can do that with shared libraries.

Comment: You can use Jenkins pipeline syntax with the shared libraries

Answer (score 1):

You were right but an other stackoverflow awnser helped me solve my issue. Strangely enough I cannot find it anymore :(.

In short:

I defined my whole pipeline deceleration as a global var (in a file called var\soaPipeline.groovy)

```
def createSOAStandardDeclarativePipeline() {
        node {
            stage('checko.....
```

Added Jenkinsfile to the code repo. The file contains the following line:

```
soaPipeline.createSOAStandardDeclarativePipeline()
```

Then configuration in jenkins:
[jenkins configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laLnW.jpg)